# Show tree result between two table related with comma

Tags: mysql, sql, relate

In MySQL my `table1` is

```
ID name parent
1  one   0
2  two   1
3  three 1
```

and my `table2` is

```
ID name parent
1  com    2,3 -->is table1.ID
```

I want to relate between `table2.parent` and `table1.id`
and show tree result :

```
com -> one -> two,three
```

How can I query it?
I query this:

```
SELECT  *
from table1 a
left join table1 b on b.parent=a.ID
where b.ID in (2,3)
```

this work nice
but didn't work this:

```
SELECT  *
from table1 a
left join table1 b on b.parent=a.ID
where b.ID in (select parent from table2)
```

Comment: So see normalisation

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select *
from table2 t2
left join table1 t1 on find_in_set(t1.id, t2.parent) > 0
group by t2.id
;
```